# Расширение Chrome: как передать в контент background-image?

Tags: css, chrome-extension

Пишу расширение для хрома. Одна из задач - добавлять на страницу дополнительные элементы-ссылки, выглядящие определенным образом. Все работает, элементы добавляются, css-классы им проставляются и задаваемые в css-файле расширения стили применяются. Но есть одна проблема: применяются все стили, кроме background-image. Если урл картинки прописать просто в виде файла, то браузер пытается ее найти на том сервере, где находится страница, и, естественно, обламывается.

CSS:

```
.newLink {    
  background-image:url('linkmarker.png');
}
```

manifest.json:

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Linker",
  "description": "Adds links",
  "version": "1.0",
  "author": "me",
  "icons": {
    "48":"icon48.png",
    "128":"icon128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "link add"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab", "storage"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
    "css": ["linker.css"],
    "js": ["linker.js"]
  }]
}
```

файл linkmarker.png лежит просто в папке с файлами расширения.
Что и куда надо прописать (и можно ли)?

Можно, конечно, добавить картинку прямо в css в base64, но менять ее будет неудобно.

UPD:
нашел вариант решения:

```
background-image:url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/linkmarker.png');
```

Но тут вообще какая-то магия случается: в веб-инспекторе в стилях добавленных ссылок свойство `background-image` имеет валидное значение `chrome-extension://afakgdclnlkjabakhoccgpgfhldhcddb/linkmarker.png` и при попытке открыть фоновую картинку в новой вкладке ее честно показывает, но сами ссылки на странице все равно остаются без фона, а в консоли лежит вот такая ошибка:

```
GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED
```

Куда дальше копать?

Comment: А если картинку на какой-то сервер закачать и давать URL с этого сервера? Конечно я понимаю что решение может быть не самое красивое, но как вариант если другие методы не сработают.

Comment: Попробуйте метод [chrome.runtime.getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL).

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы подключать файлы из локальной папки расширения - им надо дать разрешение. Для этого в manifest.json надо указать какие файлы вы хотите подключать

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "linkmarker.png"
]
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources

Поэтому я подключаю файлы через base64 (или svg без base64), это проще и часто удобнее

```
background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,...');
```

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg..."/></svg>');
```